# Multiple Cascade Paths

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with multiple cascade path error.  Here are my tables:

**Table (Companies)**
CompanyCode (PK)
....

**Table (Aircraft)**
AircraftRegistration (PK)
OwnerCode (FK to CompanyCode)
OperatorCode  (FK to CompanyCode)
....

I simply want to update the ownercode and operatorcode foreign keys in the aircraft table when I update the primary key in companies.

Is the correct way to get around this problem to use triggers?

Comment: I think triggers is the only way to deal with multiple cascade paths in SQL-Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [ON UPDATE CASCADE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186712%28v=sql.100%29) to your foreign key definitions, then the values will automatically be updated if the referenced key (i.e. Companies.CompanyCode) is changed.

**EDIT:** But as you noted in the comments, this won't work for tables that have two foreign keys referencing the same column, so for those cases you would have to use a trigger or do all your updates in a 'controlled' manner, such as through a stored procedure that updates the referencing columns. Which approach is better depends on your application design and how your database is used.

Comment: That's what I tried but it gives me the error '...may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths".  This is because I have two FK's to the same table, "OwnerCode" and "Operator Code".

Comment: My mistake, I didn't pick up on that point immediately. I've updated my answer.